# Unable to see review queues, but not sure if I was banned

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I'm unable to see any review queues, but didn't fail any audits that I'm aware of.

Following the link in the picture:https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23694879

Doesn't provide any clues either, except that a moderator disagreed with my edit approval, but that was way back on the 9th.

Does a moderator disagreeing with an approval really lead to a one-week review ban?

If so, maybe an inbox comment stating "you've been banned for this review" would be good.

Edited Edit: rene's comment links to extensive discussion confirming that this sort of edit is a bad-thing. I will now enjoy my ban and reflect on my evil-doing.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's a review ban.  "Come back" is a good indicator there.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, but why?  And does Stack Overflow make it difficult to figure out?

Comment: Do you think approving an edit that only adds backticks is an edit that makes a post better readable? See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=suggested+edits+backticks+is%3Aq

Comment: @rene I think that's subjective, but yes.  Even if I'm wrong, which I may well be, it seems a 7-day review ban is a little harsh.

Comment: Given the [reverts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5432783/majid?tab=reputation) in suggested editors reputation history, it looks like the mod went through that users revision history rejection poor edits (likely due to a mod flag) and banning reviewers where necessary, you'll need to wait for a response from them if you want a clear reasoning. AFAIK the message is custom, but just providing a link to the bad review is easiest for mods, who are busy at the best of times

Comment: eh, i do think *parts* of the edit made the post easier to read. but there were other parts of the edit that were... incorrect. reject/edit.

Comment: Ah, rene's link is extremely informative.  Well, now I know the consensus and will enjoy the remainder of my ban.

Comment: I think the key to reviewing edits well is the "skip" button -- skip any proposed edits that you're not sure of, and only accept or reject those that lie within your own area of familiarity -- same for answering questions

Comment: Heh, I didn't mean to say you're evil or evil-doing. If I have come across that way, please accept my apologies. It is just that the reviewing of these suggested edits has a different goal which we somehow didn't had a chance to communicate to you earlier.

Comment: @rene Lol, no worries.  That's purely for dramatic effect and to make the edit more interesting.  Your points are well taken.  I adjusted my edit note to make it more clear.

Comment: That `edit` was really `crappy` and should never have `been` approved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So you think it is harsh to get a 7 day ban for accepting something that goes from bad into a different bad?

#### Original

> I work on embedded linux with ConnectCore6ul.I have same issue. I have script file for sd card mounting every power on this system.This script file is "mkdir -p /media/mmcblk1p1 && mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/mmcblk1p1 /home/root/UYS/log"
>   But sometimes sdcard is read only. And I cant write a log text on sdcard.

#### The suggestion

> I work on `embedded linux` with `ConnectCore6ul` . I have the same issue. I have script file for sd card mounting every `power on` this system.
>
> This script file is
>
> > "mkdir -p /media/mmcblk1p1 && mount -t vfat -o rw /dev/mmcblk1p1 /home/root/UYS/log"
>
> But sometimes sdcard is read-only. And I cant write a `log` text on `sdcard`.

## Analysis

- Don't use backticks to emphasize words, specially if they are not code
- Do use code markup (duh) for code. A quote is not code.
- Correct all spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

There is nothing worth keeping in that suggested edit. Even if you had chosen Improve you basically had to re-do every sentence, word and markup.

A 7 day ban is not excessive at all. You as reviewer are the gatekeeper for quality content and the coach for the editors. You have done neither here. You need to do better in helping users to make quality edits and reject edits that have no basis to be improved on.

Also: [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: Personally I'd prefer to read second version if I'd open question, its looks *improved* compared to non-formatted paragraph of first. And while `such multiword` ticks `looks awful` they are not very notice-able in [review ui](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23694879). Subjectively commands and parameters are not really *code*... certain code put into `>` will actually looks better. As non-native speaker I don't see spelling/grammar problems either. You can ban me too in advance, I had it just approved in my mind.

Comment: @Sinatr there are two tabs "rendered output" and "markdown". Those sure give you all info on what has changed. At least the blockquote markup instead of code markup should have got the attention of the reviewer. None of that signal was picked up. I give you the grammar and spelling is the least of the issues here.